# svg to inline svg data compiler

Tags: svg, compilation, inline

i was wondering if there is any compiler is capable of parsing a css or scss file replacing all references to *.svg files with inline svg data. i found this:

```
body { background-image: 
    url("/assest/svg/test.svg");
  }
```

would become

```
body { background-image: 
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='10' height='10'><linearGradient id='gradient'><stop offset='10%' stop-color='%23F00'/><stop offset='90%' stop-color='%23fcc'/> </linearGradient><rect fill='url(%23gradient)' x='0' y='0' width='100%' height='100%'/></svg>");
  }
```

im looking for a way to make a portable css file without any dependencies. so far i found: https://github.com/jkphl/ but my tests so far did not show that data inlining may work. any ideas?

Comment: If you want to write a data compiler and are stuck on some part of it that's a reasonable question but asking for off site resources like "is there a data compiler available" is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Compass](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/inline-data/#inline-image) allows you to inline the image with the `inline-image` helper...

```
background-image: inline-image("/assest/svg/test.svg");
```

Comment: cool. that is even way better then what i was looking at.